# Set Printing Universes has no effect

Tags: coq, coqide

I'm following the Universes chapter in cpdt (http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html), which runs `Set Printing Universes.` to see additional comments on the types. However, I'm running CoqIde 8.6 and it has no effect.

The following code

```
Set Printing Universes.
Check Type.
```

outputs

```
Type
    : Type
```

while the book says that it should output

```
Type (* Top.3 *)
     : Type (* (Top.3)+1 *)
```

Am I missing some command? Should I use a different version of Coq?

EDIT: I just tried this in the command line with `coqtop` and it does print the type annotations. Maybe I have to enable some additional option in CoqIDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CoqIde has a specific menu for this: "View" > "Display universe levels". There are quite a few other setting that you can access from the "View" menu, but their counterpart command (`Unset Printing Notations.`, etc.) has no effect for CoqIde.